# switching back and forth between controllers in extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am building an application in extjs 4 (MVC). I often find the need to switch back and forth between two controllers. But i cant seem to find how in the documentation.

My scenario is like this.

```
Ext.define('mycontroller',{
 someMethod: function() {
 }
})

Ext.define('mycontroller1',{
 someMethod: function() {
   var someAction = function() {
     //need to call somethod in mycontroller
   }
 }
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.getController('Foo').bar();
```